How to fine-tune an LLM on a very small document
I am currently trying to fine-tune an LLM on a single document (about 1700 characters). I know that generally it is better to use prompt injection or something like a RAG system to provide specific context for a model, but I wanted to see if it would be possible to use fine-tuning instead.
Here are the details of the experiment:

Model: mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1.
The document on which the LLM was trained is a brief description of the heroes from the game Slice & Dice (link). Here is the rough structure of the document.

Heroes are the characters controlled by the player. Heroes' roles are briefly classified with color and class.
Orange heroes are assassin type heroes...
Yellow heroes are well-balanced warriors...
Grey heroes...
Red heroes are healers....
Blue heroes are spellcasters...
Green Heroes (new in V3) are a mixed class...


The model was fine-tuned using LoRA with a causal language modeling objective.

lora_config = LoraConfig(
    lora_alpha=16,
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    r=28,
    bias="none",
    target_modules=[
        "q_proj",
        "k_proj",
        "v_proj",
    ],
    task_type=TaskType.CAUSAL_LM,
)

Note about data pre-processing: all newline characters were removed, and the document was duplicated 200 times (since the document isn't large enough to even create a single batch).
After training, the model seemed to internalize (or at least memorize) the information. Here is a sample output:
<s> In the game Slice & Dice, heroes are the characters controlled by the player. Heroes' roles are briefly classified with color and class. Orange heroes are assassin type heroes that have high damage, ranged attack, poison, etc. But their defensive abilities are poor.

Some generations were not as good as others.
<s> Blue heroes In the game Slice & Dice are healers. Most of their attacks are poisoning the enemies and healing the heroes.

Next, I wanted to see if the newly taught information would remain after fine-tuning the model on an instruction dataset. So I repeated the above process, but instead of using a single document, I used the mosaicml/instruct-v3 dataset.
After training, the model seemed to learn the new instruction format, however it completely forgot the information of the initial document.
<s> [PROMPT] In the game Slice & Dice, what is the specialty of orange heroes?[RESPONSE]Orange heroes have the highest critical damage and the highest crit rate! Crit is the single most important attribute and the reason for the high crit rates! Orange heroes are your first line of defense – they will absorb most of the damage dealt to your team, but they are unable to deal as much damage as the other heroes!

Is it possible to fine-tune an LLM on a single document? And if so, are the better techniques than causal LM? What can I do to improve the above process? After training the model on a single document, can I fine-tune it on an instruction dataset without "unlearning" the information learned before?
